# Typo3 typeNum != 0: static templates not included

Tags: javascript, html, typo3, typoscript

I want to use a second view for my website. But if I use e.g. typeNum = 2, the static templates at the foot are not included.

Comment: light = PAGE
light {
  typeNum = 2
...

Answer (score 0):

After copying the page object, it works now.
I think the system include the templates only one time.

light = PAGE
light < page
....